# Will the dynamic keyword in C#4 support extension methods?

Tags: c#, dynamic, extension-methods, c#-4.0

I'm [listening to a talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Inside-C-40-dynamic-type-optional-parameters-more-COM-friendly/) about **C#4**'s `dynamic` keyword and I'm wondering... Will this feature be orthogonal to other .NET features, for example will it support extension methods?

```
public static class StrExtension {
    public static string twice(this string str) { return str + str; }
}
...
dynamic x = "Yo";
x.twice(); // will this work?
```

---

**Note:** This question was asked before C#4 was shipped which is why it's phrased in the future tense.

Comment: Awesome question.  My Guess is "No" since they aren't really part of the class, and aren't available via reflection.

Comment: I'd also guess "no".  But I think this would work:  var x = "Y0"; x.twice();

Comment: Joel, this is allready working. Changing it would be a breaking change

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From the ["New Features in C# 4" word doc](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=csharpfuture&DownloadId=3550):

> Dynamic lookup will not be able to
>   find extension methods. Whether
>   extension methods apply or not depends
>   on the static context of the call
>   (i.e. which using clauses occur), and
>   this context information is not
>   currently kept as part of the payload.

Comment: Well, that was weird... This suddenly went from three answers to one. I guess as I deleted my wrong answer, the other guy deleted his "not quite as correct answer"....

Comment: jon , in a short sentence ( just for understanding ) what is the exact reason where dynamic doesnt supports extension method ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir The magic of extension methods appears to be a compile time construct. At runtime C# isn't carrying around the state for every extension method it can find in the namespace this is a performance concern.

Answer (score 4):

This works which I find interesting at least...

```
public static class StrExtension
{
   public static string twice(this string str) { return str + str; }
}

...
dynamic x = "Yo";
StrExtension.twice(x);
```

Still, if the compiler can find the correct extension method at compile time then I don't see why it can't package up a set of extension methods to be looked up at runtime? It would be like a v-table for non-member methods.

EDIT:

This is cool... http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/multimethods.pdf

Comment: You are calling a static class and giving it a string... That should always work :)

Comment: This actually doesn't work when the string you pass is a dynamic property on a POCO object

Answer (score 2):

It can't work, Extension methods work depending on having the namespace included in the file and, as far as I know, MSIL has no idea about files and including namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method for *object* and assign it to a *dynamic*:

```
public static void MyExt(this object o) {
    dynamic d = o;
    d.myProp = "foo";
}
```

and call it like this:

```
ClassWithMyProp x;
x.MyExt();
```