# Dynamic Key word C# 4.0

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I have a property declared as type dynamic

```
 public dynamic Data {get;set;}
```

later in some method the type of data becomes System.Collections.Generic.List
so if use  Data.AsQueryable() i get "System.Collections.Generic.List`<Entity1` does not contain a definition for 'AsQueryable' " error.

The result has to be converted to Iqueryble and i am using the methods defined in Dynamic.Linq.

How should i proceed?

Comment: Ok. Good to hear it's working for you.

Comment: Just to say; `dynamic` can be **horribly** over-used... this may be one of those times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, `dynamic` doesn't work well with extension methods.

> 7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations
>
> ...if the normal processing of the
>   invocation finds no applicable
>   methods, an attempt is made to process
>   the construct as an extension method
>   invocation. If expr or any of the args
>   **has compile-time type dynamic,
>   extension methods will not apply**

As is mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258988/will-the-dynamic-keyword-in-c4-support-extension-methods), the static context (applicable `using` directives) would have to be made available at *run-time* for every dynamic call to figure out which extension methods may apply, which is currently not implemented.

Have you tried calling the extension method as a 'normal' static method instead? E.g. (please modify if you intended to call a different method):   `System.Linq.Queryable.AsQueryable(Data)`

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot, this site is really a great resource for beginners

Comment: @Daniel Joseph: Cheers. Maybe in some future version of the language, your current code "will just work".