# How to print the string array on view page in Asp.net Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
  public ActionResult About()
    {
        var roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();            

        return View();
    }
```

I don't know how to take this string on view page. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have your view accept a string[] Model and pass this model from your controller to your view like this:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
  var model = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();                   
  return View(model);
}
```

In your view you'd have something like this (assuming you are using the Razor ViewEngine):

```
@model string[]

<ul>
@foreach(var role in model) 
{
   <li>@role</li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Inside foreach loop had to use "Model".

Answer (score 1):

You can set a ViewBag

```
public ActionResult About()
{
      ViewBag.roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();                   
      return View();
}
```

and u can access this `ViewBag` object on the page by `@ViewBag.roles`

**To display the list**

```
foreach(var customrole in ViewBag.roles)
 {
    @customrole.Roles // This might be some property you need to display 
 }
```

Comment: This way it is showing System.String[] as output on view page.

Comment: You'll have to iterate through the list i have updated my answer check this post for displaying the ViewBag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521831/how-to-display-a-list-using-viewbag

Answer (score 1):

The View method takes a model which can be your string[].

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    var roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();

    return View(roles);
}
```

Then your view would look something like this

```
@model System.Array

@foreach (var role in Model)
{
    ...
}
```