# How to bind data using list of objects in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
public ActionResult CCEEvaluationGetStudentMarks(int BranchID, int ClassID, int BranchSectionID)
{
    List<object> subjectData = BindSubjects(BranchID, ClassID, BranchSectionID);

    ViewBag.subjectData = subjectData.ToList();
}

public List<object> BindSubjects(int BranchID, int ClassID, int BranchSectionID)
{
    // return db.GetAcademicSubjectDetailsforDEO(ClassID, dts.AcademicYearID).ToList();

    try
    {
        dts = GetLogOnSessionModel(); dts.PageName = "/" + this.GetType().Name + "/" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;

        List<object> d = new List<object>();

        if (dts.AccessLevelID == 5)
        {
            // staff
            if (dts.IsClassTeacher)
            {
                // classteacher
                List<GetAcademicStaffSubjectDetailsByClassTeacher_Result> data = db.GetAcademicStaffSubjectDetailsByClassTeacher(dts.PersonalID, BranchID, dts.AcademicYearID, ClassID).ToList();
                d = data.Cast<object>().ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                // ds = Sub.GetAcademicStaffSubjectDetails(int.Parse(ddlClass.SelectedValue), CoursesSession.Courses.AcademicYearID, StaffSession.Staff.StaffId, 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            List<GetAcademicSubjectDetailsforDEO_Result> data = db.GetAcademicSubjectDetailsforDEO(ClassID, dts.AcademicYearID).ToList();
            d = data.Cast<object>().ToList();
        }

        return d;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

In C# I am using different stored procedure so I put it in an object list and send to view so how can u bind the `list<object>`:

```
@foreach (var subjectHeader in ViewBag.subjectData as List<object>)
{
    <th>
        @subjectHeader
    </th>
}
```

I am new to razor please help me how to bind `viewbag` without using class file only using list of object, if it is possible or not..?

Comment: it's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521831/how-to-display-a-list-using-viewbag
try it!

Comment: actuall he is using class files but i am using object list

Comment: you can use @HTML.Raw()

Comment: It is not clear which of the methods returns your view. `CCEEvaluationGetStudentMarks` isn't returning anything (and thus won't compile), and `BindSubjects` is not returning a view, so there is no razor to talk about.

Comment: You want to send the list of object to the view and display the properties of those objects in the view? Is that what you want?