# ASP.net Foreach loop and store the data in viewbag to show on view

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, foreach

I made a foreach loop that loops through all cart_items from a specific user. I need to calculate every product total price (product price * quantity) and store that in a viewbag to show on the page itself. I don't know how I can solve this issue though. This is what I've coded (the viewbag gets overrided, so the last row, that's the value it will show):

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string user_id = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var order_id = db.Orders.Where(x => x.User_Id == user_id).Where(x => x.Paid == 0).Select(x => x.Order_Id).FirstOrDefault();
        var select_user_cart = db.Order_details.Where(x => x.Order_Id == order_id);




        var quantity_price = from x in db.Order_details
                             where x.Order_Id == order_id
                             select new { x.Quantity, x.Current_price};


        List<decimal> Calc = new List<decimal>();
        foreach (var item in quantity_price)
        {
            var quantity = item.Quantity.ToString();
            var double_quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(quantity);
            var double_price = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Current_price);

            var calc = double_quantity * double_price;
            Calc.Add(calc);               
        }
        ViewBag.Calc = Calc;


        var order_details = db.Order_details.Include(o => o.Product).Include(o => o.Order);


        return View(select_user_cart.ToList());
    }
```

[image: Table]

[image: Code]

[image: Update]

Comment: the reason is... you indeed replace the `ViewBag.Calc = calc;`. put in a list first instead of assign it directly to the `ViewBag`..

Comment: Please also add the code of view (razor) page. How you are binding the viewbag value in razor.

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: @ViewBag.Calc is a list data structure and you need to fetch items from the list and render in html. Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10522237/795683

Comment: Didn't I just do that though? I foreached through all of them, and placed all the values in the Calc List, I just dont know how to call them in HTML tho

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want is a total price of all items, you need to add to a variable for each item and add the total to viewbag instead.

```
    double total = 0;
    foreach (var item in quantity_price)
    {
        var quantity = item.Quantity.ToString();
        var double_quantity = Convert.ToDouble(quantity);
        var double_price = Convert.ToDouble(item.Current_price);

        var calc = double_quantity * double_price;
        total += calc;
    }
    ViewBag.Calc = total;
```

Comment: I have edited my post, the table is as follows: I want the price per product mutliplied by it's quantity. And if I have these values, it's also an easy calc I would say to get the real total of all prices.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to:

```
ViewBag.Calc = from x in order_details
where x.Order_Id == order_id
select (x.Quantity * x.Current_price);
```

Comment: This doesn't work because, one is an integer and the other one a string. Should I change Current_price datatype to decimal instead? So it can do it?

Comment: Use ViewBag.Calc = from x in order_details
where x.Order_Id == order_id
select (Convert.ToDouble(x.Quantity) * Convert.ToDouble(x.Current_price));

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to get viewbag list value.

Define a counter before the foreach loop.

Get item on the basis of counter.

Increase counter.

like this

```
@int i=0; //counter
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>    
    <td>@ViewBag.Calc[i]</td>  //get item from the list basis of counter.
   @i++; //increase conter value
  </tr> 
}
```

Alternative you can add a **new property to the model** and set that property in the place of the viewbag and use as you are using other properties of the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property name total in your model (ex: quantity, current_price) and assign the total value to it. Or you can use `ViewBag.Calc` as an array, but I think if you do use array it could also result in a problem. Make a list of type decimal or something like this:

```
List <decimal> total = new <decimal>();
foreach (var item in quantity_price)
{
    var quantity = item.Quantity.ToString();
    var double_quantity = Convert.ToDouble(quantity);
    var double_price = Convert.ToDouble(item.Current_price);

    var calc = double_quantity * double_price;
    total.add(calc)
}

ViewBag["calc"] = total;
```

In view:

```
@int count=0; 
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

<tr>
    <td>@ViewBag.Calc[count]</td>  
   @count++;
  </tr>

}
```

Comment: I cant make a variable in the view.. anyway how to do this?

Comment: Okay, so I got it, but it still only takes only the first item out of the list/ You can see the multipliers that it only works on hte first item. And it prints out 0++.. What now D:

Comment: plz, provide ur code,, actually it suppose to work... thanks,,

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following code. The only thing that happens right now, is that the counter actually shows behind the price. But the calculatians are correct. Thanks to everyone that helped me. (If you know a fix on how to disable showing that counter, I'd love to hear it.)

VIEW:

```
@{ int counter = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Current_price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
    </td>
    <td>
        @ViewBag.Calc[counter]
        @(counter++)

    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Order_details_Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Order_details_Id })
    </td>
</tr>
        }
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
List<decimal> Calc = new List<decimal>();
        foreach (var item in quantity_price)
        {
            var quantity = item.Quantity.ToString();
            var double_price = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Current_price);
            var calc = item.Quantity * double_price;
            Calc.Add(calc);               
        }
        ViewBag.Calc = Calc;
```