# How to pass and access by index a list of strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't want to use models since it's a really simple app. Basically I have a list of strings that I want to pass to View either via Viewbag or Viewdata (doesn't matter) and then display each item in a specific place by accessing it via index.e.g list[0],list[1] and so on. I know the number of items in the list and don't want to loop through them as it doesn't give me the display control that I need.

thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can pass the collection through the ViewBag. Yes, you can access it by index. Have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a list using ViewBag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521831/how-to-display-a-list-using-viewbag)