# asp.net mvc razor veiwbag is not working with entity frame work tolist()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am trying bind data in my **chtml** page using **viewbag**,but its not working.

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult ViewInvoice(decimal id)
        {
            var invoice_data = db.Invoices    // your starting point - table in the "from" statement
                            .Join(db.Users, a => a.CreatedBy, b => b.UserID, (a, b) => new { a.VehicleID, a.VehicleCheckOut, a.InvoiceID, a.InvoiceStatus, a.ChargeAmount, a.VehicleNo, a.VehicleRiderName, a.VehicleRiderPhone, a.IsVehicleExtra, a.VehicleCheckIn, a.VehicleLimitOut, b.UserFirstName, b.UserLastName, b.CreatedOn })
                            .Join(db.ParkingStatus, a => a.InvoiceStatus, b => b.PStatusID, (a, b) => new { b.PStatusName, b.PStatusKey, a.VehicleID, a.VehicleCheckOut, a.InvoiceID, a.InvoiceStatus, a.ChargeAmount, a.VehicleNo, a.VehicleRiderName, a.VehicleRiderPhone, a.IsVehicleExtra, a.VehicleCheckIn, a.VehicleLimitOut, a.UserFirstName, a.UserLastName, a.CreatedOn })
                            .Join(db.Vehicles, a => a.VehicleID, b => b.VehicleID, (a, b) => new { a.PStatusName, a.PStatusKey, a.VehicleCheckOut, a.InvoiceID, a.InvoiceStatus, a.ChargeAmount, a.VehicleNo, a.VehicleRiderName, a.VehicleRiderPhone, a.IsVehicleExtra, a.VehicleCheckIn, a.VehicleLimitOut, b.VehicleName, a.UserFirstName, a.UserLastName, a.CreatedOn })
                           .Join(db.ParkingStatus, // the source table of the inner join
                               sp => sp.InvoiceStatus,        // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
                               st => st.PStatusID,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
                               (sp, st) => new { sp.PStatusName, sp.PStatusKey, sp.UserFirstName, sp.UserLastName, sp.CreatedOn, sp.VehicleCheckOut, sp.InvoiceID, sp.VehicleCheckIn, sp.VehicleLimitOut, sp.IsVehicleExtra, sp.VehicleRiderName, sp.VehicleRiderPhone, sp.ChargeAmount, sp.VehicleName }).Where(x => x.InvoiceID == id).ToList();


            ViewBag.invoice_data = invoice_data;
            return View();
        }
```

I am trying to access with below but its not work

```
@((ViewBag.invoice_data as List<PMS.Models.Invoice>).First().InvoiceID)
```

**Below is the error**

**My Chtml page**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Invoice";
    ViewBag.MainTitle = "View Invoice";
}
<section class="invoice">
                                @((ViewBag.invoice_data as List<PMS.Models.Invoice>).First().InvoiceID)
                            </section>
```

[image: Error]

Comment: could you please elaborate on `but its not work`

Comment: @Alex its getting error

Comment: what error? Please give us the information, we can't help otherwise! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Alex,i have edit my question and  add error.kindly check the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a list using ViewBag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521831/how-to-display-a-list-using-viewbag)

Comment: Do you have this line in the beginning of your cshtml? @using PMS.Models

Comment: i am using @((ViewBag.invoice_data as List<PMS.Models.Invoice>).First().InvoiceID)

Comment: i have made some changes but i am getting new error Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Comment: this is probably because your ViewBag doesn't contain anything. Breakpoint on `            ViewBag.invoice_data = invoice_data;` and check `invoice_data` is not null / empty

Answer (score 1):

in your controller code

```
(sp, st) => new { sp.PStatusName,
```

this is an anonymous type so the `as` (in the view) fails and returns null

Try

```
(sp, st) => new PMS.Models.Invoice { sp.PStatusName,
```

BTW: the use of a strongly typed view would be much much safer.