# Converting from Var to Dynamic list and perform operations

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic, var

I have below type of code snippet.

```
var PersonList = new List<person>() { 
                new person { Name = "b", Age = 4 },
                new person { Name = "s", Age = 2 },
                new person { Name = "e", Age = 5 },
                new person { Name = "a", Age = 1 },
            }.AsQueryable();

// Now somewhere in usercontrol I am converting that list to dynamic.
dynamic DynaList = PersonList;

// Now below line gives me error when I try to perform any on DynaList.
DynaList.ToList(); // Error - BinderException
DynaList.OrderBy("Name"); // Error - BinderException
```

Why dynamic is not converting to its type runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use extension methods on dynamic types, as if the extension method was a method on the instance.  See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258988/will-the-dynamic-keyword-in-c4-support-extension-methods).  You have to use the extension methods on the underlying static class.

Comment: If you see a duplicate, please vote to close, rather than link it in an answer to scrape some rep.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods are not supported on dynamic types . Hope this [Link](http://andersnoras.com/post/100787365/c-4-0-why-dynamic-binding-and-extension-methods) will explain you the reason...