# Why can't my program determine which extension method to use on a dynamic variable?

Tags: c#, dynamic, extension-methods

I have a `dynamic value` which I have created a couple extension methods for as follows:

```
public static bool IsA(this object obj, Type t)
{
    return ObjectExtensions.Methods.IsA(obj, t);
}

public static bool IsA(this string obj, Type t)
{
    return t == typeof (string);
}
```

The content of the above methods is out of the scope for this question, but the method headers should show that I have two extension methods: one on `object` and one on `string`.

The code that is actually trying to utilize the above code is here:

```
if (!(value.IsA(typeof(string))))
{
    //...
}
```

In the above snippet, `value` could be a `string`, an `IEnumerable`, a model generated from my EF scaffold, etc... It's dynamic.

My issue is that when the type of `value` is a string, I get the error:

`RuntimeBinderException: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsA'`

which is a total lie, because when I manually cast `value` to `string` via `((string)value)`, the `IsA` method is suddenly found.

How do I get my extension to work without having to manually cast to a type? (which defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do (abstract all the crap from checking what something is))

Comment: "because in c# there is no common ancestor between all types"??? - `System.Object`

Comment: "in c# there is no common ancestor between all types" => ummm... `object`?

Comment: `string` does *not* contain a definition for `IsA`. You can verify this by running `typeof(string).GetMethods("IsA")`. Whether it should see your extension method (a static method like any other) or not is another thing :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will the dynamic keyword in C#4 support extension methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258988/will-the-dynamic-keyword-in-c4-support-extension-methods)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extension method and dynamic object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object)

Comment: @Igor I somewhere earlier today that they were seperate -- something about value types vs object types. But looking at the MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx  It clearly says that string is a type of object. Even decimals are an object (cause decimal is a ValueType) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx  I'll update my question to remove the erroneous statement.

Comment: @jon That reply is for you as well ^

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli - value types vs reference types

Comment: @CoderDennis that question seems to be the closest to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic is determined at runtime. Unfortunately, the DLR doesn't consider extension methods - those are compile-time sugar.

You can, however, do this:

`IsA(value, typeof(string))`

Extension methods are really just regular static methods with some syntactic sugar that lets you treat them like methods on that instance, even though it's really not.

Edit:
Alternately, you should be able to cast the dynamic to `System.Object`, and then invoke the extension method, like so:

`(value as object).IsA(typeof(string))`

Comment: thanks for your clear, concise answer. Not ideal, but it'll do for now, I guess.