# Unable to call extension method during runtime for dynamic variable

Tags: c#

Below is the sample code and it is throwing error ('`'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToUpperExtn'`') during runtime. How can i handle this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic name = "Prasad";
        **Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(name).ToUpperExtn());** // Error: ''string' does not contain a definition for 'ToUpperExtn''

        string name1 = "Prasad";
        Console.WriteLine(name1.ToUpperExtn()); // Working fine
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToUpperExtn(this string value)
    {
        return value.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will the dynamic keyword in C#4 support extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258988/will-the-dynamic-keyword-in-c4-support-extension-methods)

Comment: The following works however: `string s = Convert.ToString(name); Console.WriteLine(s.ToUpperExtn()); `. Interesting.

Comment: And also `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString((object)name).ToUpperExtn());`. So the problem is that the compiler cannot deduce the type of the expression `Convert.ToString(name)` and the runtime resolutions does not consider extension methods.

Comment: This already has been answered years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object