# C# Dynamics, System,DateTime and extension methods

Tags: c#

I get enumerable dynamic objects back from a database class which are declared like

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> sessions = null
```

I have an extended method that humanising datetimes, adding the day ordinals etc.

```
DateTime.Now.HumanisedDate()
```

This works find but I cant apply the extension method directly on the dynamic object

```
session.STARTDATE.HumanisedDate()
```

but GetType() for session.STARTDATE says System.DateTime

If I do this

```
DateTime whatever = session.STARTDATE;
whatever.HumanisedDate()
```

All is good. I'd like to understand why session.STARTDATE is reported as being a DateTime type but I cannot apply a DateTime extension to it. Thanks all.

Comment: Thank you, glad to know I wasnt going mad!

Answer (score 0):

[Will the dynamic keyword in C#4 support extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258988/will-the-dynamic-keyword-in-c4-support-extension-methods)

and

[Extension method and dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object)

Go into some detail about why extension methods are not available on dynamic objects.